# How can I monitor data usage only when connected to a specific gateway?

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-monitoring, gateway

I have a laptop that I connect to different network. I have a limited data plan at home and I want to monitor data usage only at home network.

I know vnstat monitors interface only and it is not possible to monitor a when connected to a specific gateway like netwrox in windows does. Is there any work around for this in ubuntu?